# How to make badges in input like that of stack overflow tags in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I want an input/textarea which can allow users to add bootstrap `badges`. A new `badge` will be added when the user presses spacebar after some text, just like SO tag field (pls see screenshot). Also Every `badge` must contain an x icon, which, when pressed, removes that particular `badge`.
How to achieve this just by bootstrap?

Comment: Use this https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ .  Check this codepen as well https://codepen.io/nsei/pen/zqJEOy?editors=1100

Comment: @Shiladitya  Thanks but I already know about that. Is it possible to achieve it without JQuery?. I am using angular4 and want to avoid JQuery as much as possible.

Comment: Here you go http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

Comment: @Shiladitya Its angularJs. I am using angular 4

Comment: You need to be more specific when you are asking a question. Every time someone is giving a solution, you are just asking for next stage of the question, **that's not correct**. Update your question.

Comment: @Shiladitya I am sorry for the inconvenience. I didn't give the information that I was using angular 4 because I was expecting a pure bootstrap solution. And it's clearly mentioned in the question that I am expecting a pure bootstrap solution.

Answer (score 0):

Download CSS files from below github link 
[ng-tags-input.min](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/releases/download/v3.2.0/ng-tags-input.min.zip) and [ng-tags-input](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/releases/download/v3.2.0/ng-tags-input.zip)
and Create a controller like below.

```
> <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
>     <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
>     <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>   </body>
```

Add below in App.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];
});
```

Source: [Demo](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos/)

Comment: I am using angular4. Any angular4 specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

Came here using React. Best solution:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tagsinput

Side Tip:
By default, the tags are added when you hit `Enter` or `Tab`.

If you need to have the tags be added on "Spacebar" just add `addKeys={[32]}` to the `TagsInput`, like this:

```
    <TagsInput
      onChange={onChange}
      value={tags}
      addKeys={[32]}
    />
```